# Building swagger-codegen on Windows - is it ok to use Git Bash?

Tags: scala, windows-7-x64, git-bash, swagger

I am attempting to build [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen) on Windows 7 x64. I ran into a problem when I had to run `./sbt assembly`. I couldn't see how to do it from the Windows command prompt.

Instead, I ran it from Git-Bash. It ran successfully, with warnings, but no errors.

Is this an acceptable solution?

I ask because I am stuck on the next step running the template client for petstore.

`./bin/scala-petstore.sh` produces the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class Files`

Comment: "I couldn't see how to do it from the Windows command prompt."

What problems did you run into when trying to run this from the Windows command prompt?

Comment: @adhominem I couldn't execute `sbt` because it is a bash script.

Comment: There's an sbt.bat, at least in the package I have

Comment: @adhominem interesting, where did you get your package? In the root of the link above there is no `sbt.bat`. https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen

Comment: At the official sbt site, http://www.scala-sbt.org/

Comment: @adhominem That worked, thanks. I'll fork and update the `README.MD` at github.

Comment: I'll answer the question then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official SBT distribution at [scala-sbt.org](http://scala-sbt.org) includes an sbt.bat-file that works on windows.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the OP was successful in running sbt on Windows 7. However, I believe the OP issue comes from running the scala-petstore.sh script.

I have found the swagger generation scripts depend on a bash shell. However, on Windows Git Bash shell, the basic scala executable does not works. Run "scala -version" on Windows from a CMD shell and you get the scala version. Run "scala -version" on Windows from a GitBash shell and you get: 
  $ scala -version
  Error: Could not find or load main class Files

Answered in another question/topic: [Does anyone know how to run the scala executable in Git Bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238486/does-anyone-know-how-to-run-the-scala-executable-in-git-bash-shell/27243518#27243518)